# Cannot connect to WPA2, but connecting to WEP is fine

Tags: debian, wifi, wpa-supplicant, wpa

I'm trying to set up a connection to a WPA2-Personal network on a barebones Debian install. I've installed the firmware for my wireless adapter just fine (ipw2200) and can connect to open wireless networks perfectly. I've run through Debian's WiFi/HowToUse documentation a few times now, and each time it doesn't work. Here's my current configuration files:

`/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto MyOpenNetwork inet dhcp
    wireless-ssid MyOpenNetworkSSID

auto MyWPANetwork inet dhcp
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/MyWPANetwork.conf
```

`/etc/wpa_supplicant/MyWPANetwork.conf`:

```
network={
    ssid="MyWPASSID"
    psk=LotsOfHexGeneratedBywpa_passphrase
}
```

Also, running `ifup eth1=MyNetwork` throws:

```
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
```

And `wpa_supplicant -D wext -i eth1 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/MyWPANetwork.conf` throws:

```
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
eth1: Trying to associate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (SSID='MyWPASSID' freq=XXXX MHz)
eth1: Association request to the driver failed
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: From the output I think you have a typo, but I'm not sure why. At any rate take a look at this AU Q&A which has a link to the ref docs for setting up WPA etc. It's in the A from Bhodi: http://askubuntu.com/questions/106633/wpa-supplicant-ioctlsiocsiwencodeext-invalid-argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question to close; it seems the issue is on the network's end and not mine, I've since been able to connect to other WPA2 networks just fine.